# Using a UIPanGesture to drag a tableView/scrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I suppose the best way to describe the control, that I'm trying to make, is a tableView that could be dragged left and right and then scrolled up and down. There's no tabs, or anything else that the user touches just table view and it's cells.

I've read the documentation on UIScrollView and UITableView and there wasn't much in there :( Then again there might have been stuff I've missed

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's for a side panel that can be dragged and flicked away, but the panel has a scroll view or a table that can be scrolled up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the UITableView as a sub view of a UIScrollView (which can scroll only in horizontal direction) ? Take a look at https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView

Comment: I've been using the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods to help with my situation. I've quickly looked over the description and this might help me on my task. I'll give you more updates as I move ahead thank you.

Comment: -->The solution is quite simple. Have a view with the pan gesture for dragging and then add the tableView/scrollView on top of that. That way the two gestures aren't fighting each other.

That's it. Thank you Sandeep for showing me this great little project. I found my solution after seeing what they did to remedy their problem.